# Connect to MQ 5.2 queue using a remote queue in MQ 7

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I want to know if it is possible to connect to a IBM MQ 5.2 queue using a remote queue in IBM MQ 7. 
I want to achieve this since I have to connect to two different queue managers in different machines in the same application. I read about using CCDT file as well. But I don't have access to those files as well. Therefore I need to know above mentioned operation is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any version of WMQ QMgr can talk to any other version of WMQ QMgr.  However, V5.2 has been out of support on most platforms for about a decade.  That means V7.1 was never tested against it and there is no official support for this configuration.

That said, there is nothing preventing you from using the CCDT files.  If you download [SupportPac MO72](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO72), that tool is capable of defining CCDT files at different versions.  I don't know if it goes as far back as V5.2, however if not you can try the oldest version it can define and specify the bare minimum of channel features - QMgr, IP address, port, channel name.

Incidentally, there is no need to worry about using SSL channels for a connection to a V5.2 QMgr because it never received patches for security vulnerabilities discovered since it went out of support.  Among these were vulnerabilities to the SSL protocol itself, as well as MD5 and SHA-1, all of which are fixed in any current version of WMQ.  If you take SSL out of the picture, connecting to a v5.2 QMgr is like connecting to any other QMgr.  Set the `MQSERVER` environment variable and make a connection.  Your client app should handle it fine without a CCDT.